# Retrieving documents from sharepoint 2010 document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am uploading a document to Document library. Along with this I am creating a field called 'FieldID' by combining 2 values. However I am unable to see this field in the document library and hence unable to query the document with this field.How can I see this field or how can I retrieve documents using this 'FieldID'. This is the code.

```
if (UploadFile.PostedFile != null || (UploadFile.PostedFile.ToString() != string.Empty))
{                               
    String fileName = UploadFile.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();                
    string userLogin = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;                
    Guid siteID = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
    SPDocumentLibrary exposureLibrary = null;
    SPList listDoc = null;
    SPFolder myLibrary = null;

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(siteID))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;   
                // exposureLibrary
                try
                {
                   // Check if the document library already exists
                    exposureLibrary = (oWeb.Lists[SharepointCommon.Constants.USERINTERFACECUSTOMIZATIONSFEATURERECEIVER_EXPOSURE_DOCUMENTLIBRARY_NAME] as SPDocumentLibrary);

                    exposureLibrary.ContentTypesEnabled = false;
                    exposureLibrary.EnableAttachments = false;
                    exposureLibrary.EnableFolderCreation = false;
                    exposureLibrary.EnableVersioning = true;
                    exposureLibrary.NoCrawl = true;
                    exposureLibrary.OnQuickLaunch = false;
                    /* create a Text field for ID */


                    SPFieldText field = (exposureLibrary.Fields["FILEID"] as SPFieldText);

                // Check if the field is available
                    if (field == null)
                    {
                        SPFieldText fldID = (SPFieldText)exposureLibrary.Fields.CreateNewField(
                                        SPFieldType.Text.ToString(), "FILEID");
                        fldID.Required = true;
                        fldID.MaxLength = 100;
                        fldID.Hidden = false;
                        exposureLibrary.Fields.Add(fldID);
                    }
                    //exposureLibrary.Update();
                    myLibrary = exposureLibrary.RootFolder;

                }
                catch
                {

                    // Determine the GUID of the document library
                    Guid ExposureDocumentLibraryId = oWeb.Lists.Add(SharepointCommon.Constants.USERINTERFACECUSTOMIZATIONSFEATURERECEIVER_EXPOSURE_DOCUMENTLIBRARY_NAME, SharepointCommon.Constants.USERINTERFACECUSTOMIZATIONSFEATURERECEIVER_EXPOSURE_DOCUMENTLIBRARY_DESCRIPTION, SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);

                    listDoc = oWeb.Lists[ExposureDocumentLibraryId];

                    /* create a Text field for ID */

                    SPFieldText fldID = (SPFieldText)listDoc.Fields.CreateNewField(
                                    SPFieldType.Text.ToString(), "FILEID");
                    fldID.Required = true;
                    fldID.MaxLength = 100;
                    fldID.Hidden = false;
                    listDoc.Fields.Add(fldID);

                    // Set properties of the document library
                    listDoc.ContentTypesEnabled = false;
                    listDoc.EnableAttachments = false;
                    listDoc.EnableFolderCreation = false;
                    listDoc.EnableVersioning = true;
                    listDoc.NoCrawl = true;
                    listDoc.OnQuickLaunch = false;                                
                    listDoc.Update();
                    myLibrary = listDoc.RootFolder;
                }


                // Prepare to upload
                Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;


                // Upload document
                SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(UploadFile.FileName + "(" + ViewState[UIConstants.CUSTOMERID].ToString() + " - "+ViewState[UIConstants.MondiPlantID].ToString()+ ")", UploadFile.FileContent, replaceExistingFiles);
                //spfile.Item["FILEID"]= ViewState[UIConstants.CUSTOMERID].ToString() + " _ " + ViewState[UIConstants.MondiPlantID].ToString();
                //myLibrary.Item["ID"] = ViewState[UIConstants.CUSTOMERID].ToString() + " _ " + ViewState[UIConstants.MondiPlantID].ToString();
                spfile.Item.Update();
                oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;`enter code here`

                // Commit 
                myLibrary.Update();
                // Update the document library
                oWeb.Update();                           
            }
        }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

exposureLibrary.Fields.Add(fldID); //after this step

//exposureLibrary.Update();

you need to uncomment this, because after a field is created in try block, list/library is not being updated

Comment: Any further help. I want to retrieve the documents from document Library based on some condition and show them as link. When the link is clicked, the document should be opened.

Thanks for any help..